# FFmpeg file conversion exceeds maximum execution time

Tags: php, shell, video, ffmpeg, exec

I have a file upload system the checks the file format, etc and converts to an mp4 if necessary. This works fine as long as the video file(s) total length is less than 30 seconds.
I have been testing this two short clips about 10 seconds each and it work fine but when I test this with a clip that this 33 seconds I get the error :

> **Fatal error**:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\own_it_all\global.func\file_upload.php** on line
>   **59**

I could just increase the maximum execution time in the php.ini file but as the max length of a video is 20 mins this wouldn't seem very user friendly making the user wait 20 mins per video.
Is there a way of converting the video instantly or as near as?

This is the exec cmd i have:

```
$cmd = "ffmpeg -i $input -vcodec h264 -acodec aac -strict -2 $o";
```

As the up-loader allows multiple uploads this is inside a for loop.

```
foreach($_FILES['file']['name'] as $key => $name){
        if($_FILES['file']['error'][$key] === 0){
            $temp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$key];
            $ext = explode('.',$name);
            $ext = strtolower(end($ext));
            $_file = md5($temp).time();
            $file = $_file.'.'.$ext;
            if(in_array($ext,$allowed) === true &&  move_uploaded_file($temp,"../uploads/{$file}") === true){
                $file_type = explode('/',$_FILES['file']['type'][$key]);
                if($file_type[0] === 'image'){
                    $succedeed[] = array('name' => $name,'file' => $file, 'type' => 'image');               
                }else{
                    $ffmpeg = 'ffmpeg';
                    $output = dirname(__DIR__).'/uploads/thumbs/'.$_file.'.jpg';
                    $input = dirname(__DIR__).'/uploads/'.$file;
                    $mov = new ffmpeg_movie($input);
                    $d =  $mov->getDuration();
                    $iscopy = $mov->getCopyright();
                    $h = $mov->getFrameHeight();
                    $w = $mov->getFrameWidth();
                    $pos = ceil((int)$d /3);
                    $size = $w.'x'.$h;
                    $i = explode('.',$input);
                    $o = $i[0].'.mp4';
                    if(ceil($d) < 1200){
                        if($ext != 'mp4'){
                            $cmd = "ffmpeg -i $input -vcodec h264 -acodec aac -strict -2 $o";
                            //$cmd = "ffmpeg -i $input -vcodec h264 -acodec aac -s $size $o";
                            shell_exec($cmd);
                            $toclear[] = array('file' => $file);
                        }
                        $cmd = "ffmpeg -ss $pos -i $o -an -s $size $output";
                        shell_exec($cmd);
                        $total_time += $pos;
                        $succedeed[] = array('name' => $name,'file' => 'thumbs/'.$_file.'.jpg', 'type' => 'mp4');                           

                    }else{
                        $failed[] = array('name' => $name, 'file' => $file, 'error' => 'Video length cannot exceed 20mins.');
                    }           
                }

            }else{
                $failed[] = array('name' => $name, 'file' => $file, 'error' => 'File type not allowed');
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your php ini and set Max Execution Time. In my case, 5 min of video is more than 30 min of conversion with ffmpeg.
You can use ajax for call your "converter" php script and put a "loader" with jscript.

Comment: Sounds more better, if I understand you mean:
1. upload the files - show current progress bar
2. convert files - show new progress bar

Comment: Correct! But I think it's difficult get ffmpeg progress... It's better show a "loading..." message.